# Sendgrid node.js send directly to spam

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

My goal is to send an email from node.js server directly user's email, I'm using Sendgrid to send these email. It works, but the problem is, it sent directly to spam folder. Here's the code that I copied from Sendgrid website

```
        const helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
        const from_email = new helper.Email("testing2@gmail.com");
        const to_email = new helper.Email(user.email)
        const subject = "Reset your password on Hackathon Starter";
        const content = new helper.Content("text/plain", `You are receiving this email because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n
        Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n
        http://${req.headers.host}/reset/${token}\n\n
        If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n`);

        const mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

        const sg = require('sendgrid')('APIKEY');
        const request = sg.emptyRequest({
          method: 'POST',
          path: '/v3/mail/send',
          body: mail.toJSON()
        });

        sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
          console.log(response.statusCode);
          console.log(response.body);
          console.log(response.headers);
        });
```

What are the requirements for me to fulfill so that it will send directly to user's inbox?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this problem is coming from your code itself. If the mail has reached the intended inbox (even in the spam folder), your code is alright. It can come from various settings, I advice you to read this vblog post from sendgrid : https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/

Answer (score 1):

In my case my emails are marked as spam because of the anchor label different to the href being actually called.
And that's because of the 'click tracking' setting of sendgrid.

So, if you have something like

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com">yourdomain.com</a>
```

sendgrid may replace the href and you end up with something like:

```
<a href="http://sendgrid.net/....<very-long-url>.......">yourdomain.com</a>
```

The sendgrid page being called tracks the click and then redirects the user to the url you originally set. But this sometimes results in your email being marked as spam.

Try to set 'click tracking' in sendgrid dashboard to off: settings | tracking | click tracking.

details here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/tracking/